# Нужна подсказка в написании SQL-запроса на UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы **Zakazi** и **Isp_zak**

В таблице Zakazi след. столбцы:
id_table, kod_kl,  pod_kod_exped , kod_kl_grotpr, u_kod, vesgr, count_vag, CodeGruN, vocode, period_per, dt_zak, stcode , nnod, kod_jd, zak_comlite, smgs

В таблице Isp_zak след.стобцы:
id_table, pod_kod_exped, nomot, nomvag, kodgr, dt_otpr, stotpr, dvydsd, stnds, abr_val, vesgr, uni_id, messvid, id_table_zak

Нужно написать **UPDATE** для таблицы **Isp_zak** для поля **id_table_zak** данными из таблицы **zakazi** из поля **id_table**.
При условии, чтобы количество повторяющихся значений **id_table** заказов не превышало значения **count_vag** из таблицы **Zakazi**?

С реализацией этих условий всё просто Zakazi.pod_kod_exped = Isp_zak.pod_kod_exped and Zakazi.CodeGruN = Isp_zak.kodgr and Zakazi.dt_zak < Isp_zak.dt_otpr

Comment: @E-Sergey прошу пояснить ваш вопрос, т.к. он включает несколько понятных только вам условий

Comment: UPDATE iz
  SET iz.Isp_zak = z.id_table
  FROM Isp_zak AS iz
  INNER JOIN (
             SELECT
                pod_kod_exped
                ,CodeGruN
                ,dt_zak
                ,count(id_table) OVER (PARTITION BY id_table) AS  [количество повторяющихся значений id_table]
                ,count_vag 
             FROM Zakazi
             )  AS z
  ON z.pod_kod_exped = iz.pod_kod_exped and z.CodeGruN = iz.kodgr and z.dt_zak < iz.dt_otpr
  WHERE z.[количество повторяющихся значений id_table] >= z.count_vag

Comment: @SergeNazarenko В таблице Zakazi поле count_vag это количество контейнеров.
А в таблице Isp_zak указываются данные о предоставленных заказах, но по 1-му контейнеру.
Нужно сопоставить эти данные. Т.е. проставить id заказа к определенным записям в таблице исполненных, но количество контейнеров соответствующих одному заказу не должно превышать указанное в заказе.

Comment: @e-sergey я правильно понимаю, что апдейт нужен только в тех строках таблицы Isp_zak, где количество nomvag не превышает числа count_vag из таблицы Zakazi по соответствующему заказу?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko Да

Answer (score 2):

Данный запрос будет работать на версии SQL Server 2008 и выше

```
UPDATE iz
SET iz.Isp_zak = z.id_table
FROM Isp_zak AS iz
INNER JOIN (
         SELECT
            pod_kod_exped
            ,CodeGruN
            ,dt_zak
            ,count(id_table) OVER (PARTITION BY id_table) AS  [количество повторяющихся значений id_table]
            ,count_vag 
         FROM Zakazi
         )  AS z
ON z.pod_kod_exped = iz.pod_kod_exped and z.CodeGruN = iz.kodgr and z.dt_zak < iz.dt_otpr
WHERE z.[количество повторяющихся значений id_table] >= z.count_vag
```